# What is the probability of being in a "run" of length $k$?

Tags: probability

Consider an infinite sequence $(s_n)$ of $0$'s and $1$'s such that the sequence contains 50% $0$'s and 50% $1$'s.  Let a "run" be any subsequence consisting of only $0$'s or $1's$.

What is probability that an element $s_n$ chosen at random will reside in a run of length $k$?

Based on heuristic reasoning, I think that the answer is
\begin{align}
  p(k) = \frac{k\,2^{-k}}{\sum_{j}j 2^{-j}}.
\end{align}

Is this correct?  Is there a special name for this problem?

**Heuristic reasoning.** Consider a long sequence with $N$ runs.  The probability that any given run is of length $k$ is $2^{-k}$, so the total number of elements of the sequence residing in a run of length $k$ is $k2^{-k} N$.  Now divide this by the total length of the sequence which is $\sum_k j2^{-j}N$.  The $N$'s drop out and you get $p(k)$ as above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One is in a run of length $k$ if, for some $i$, the following events happen:

- $i$ entries after the current position coincide with the entry at the current position
- $k-i-1$ entries before the current position coincide with the entry at the current position
- the next entries before and after the current position do not coincide with it.

These events are disjoint for different values of $i$, each has probability $1/2^{k+1}$, and exactly the integers $i$ such that $0\leqslant i\leqslant k-1$ are valid hence there are $k$ of them. Finally, for every $k\geqslant1$, $$P(\text{run of length exactly}\ k)=k/2^{k+1}.{}$$

Comment: Thanks.  This agrees with the expression I wrote it seems since $\sum_j j 2^{-j} = 2$.

Comment: @Did It seems that I have downvoted your answer instead of upvoted it. Can you please edit your answer? Thanks.

Comment: @Krokop Done. $ $